# Objective-c division does not match manual calculation

Tags: objective-c, math

Now here's a strange issue. The result for a division is different with objective-c and my manual solution. Obviously I first assumed my solution to be wrong, but either I'm missing something or... It isn't.

Here's the code:

```
GLfloat t = (gone - delay) / kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration;
NSLog(@"%f %f %f", (gone - delay), kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration, t);
```

This logs `0.017853 3.500000 3.035706`. Which means that `0.017853 / 3.500000` should be `3.035706`, right ??? Wrong. It actually is `0.00510085714286`. The number is not that small that would give precision issues, and even so, it would probably round of to something like 0.0... Am I missing something??

Edit with the full code:

```
- (void)animateIn:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSArray *buttons = @[self.registrationButton];//, self.facebookButton, self.linkedInButton, self.twitterButton];
    NSDate *when = [timer userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval gone = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:when];
    NSUInteger finished = 0;

    for (int it=0 ; it < [buttons count] ; ++it) {

        UIButton *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:it];
        GLfloat toValue = self.registrationView.frame.origin.y + 37 + button.frame.size.height * it + 10 * it;
        GLfloat fromValue = toValue + self.view.frame.size.height;
        GLfloat delay = kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimateInDelayFactor * it;
        CGRect frame;

        // Have we waited enough for this button?
        if (gone >= delay) {

            // Use the timing function
            GLfloat t = (gone - delay) / kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration;
            NSLog(@"%f %f %f", (gone - delay), kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration, t);

//            t = [HyEasing easeOutBounce:t];

            // Is the animation finished for this button?
            if (t >= 1.0f) {
                t = 1.0f;
                ++finished;
                continue;
            }

            // Compute current displacement
            GLfloat displacement = fabs(toValue - fromValue);
            GLfloat y = toValue + displacement * (1.0f - t);

            // Create the frame for the animation
            frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
        }

        // Make sure the button is at its initial position
        else frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, fromValue, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

        [button setFrame:frame];
    }

    if (finished == [buttons count]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's something you're not telling us.  (Eg, is there any time elapsed between the two statements?)

Comment: Show the definition of `kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration`. Is it a preprocessor macro with a compound expression that's not enclosed in parentheses?

Comment: Damn it -.-; you are right! It's defined as `0.5f + 3` (no parenthesis). How could I forget about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration` is a preprocessor macro with a compound expression that's not enclosed in parentheses. So, when it was incorporated into another compound expression, the terms of `kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration` associated more strongly with terms of the containing expression than with each other, changing the order of operations.

That is,

```
(gone - delay) / kHyAuthenticationViewControllerAnimationDuration
```

expanded to:

```
(gone - delay) / 0.5f + 3
```

which evaluated like:

```
((gone - delay) / 0.5f) + 3
```

Comment: That is correct. It's been quite a few years since I've been bitten by this :P thanks.